# Solving the scattering field equations to get FDTD equations

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, computational-physics

I was going through a paper  [*FDTD method for the scattered-field equation to calculate the radar cross-section of a three-dimensional target*](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10825-018-1162-4) published in the Journal of Computational Electronics(2018). They had a pair of equations given by:
$\epsilon\frac{\partial E_s}{\partial t} + \sigma_eE_s=\nabla\times H_s+(\epsilon_0 - \epsilon)\frac{\partial E_i}{\partial t} - \sigma_eE_i$

$\mu \frac{\partial H_s}{\partial t} + \sigma_mH_s=-\nabla \times E_s+(\mu_0-\mu)\frac{\partial H_i}{\partial t} - \sigma_mH_i$

The Finite-Difference-Time-Domain(FDTD) iterative solutions to this pair of equations is given by -

$E_S^{n+1}=\frac{\epsilon - \sigma_e\Delta t /2}{\epsilon + \sigma_e \Delta t/2}E_s^n+\frac{\Delta t}{\epsilon +\sigma_e \Delta t/2} \nabla\times H_s^{n+1/2}+\frac{(\epsilon_0 -\epsilon) -\sigma_e\Delta t/2}{\epsilon + \sigma_e\Delta t/2}E_i^{n+1}-\frac{(\epsilon_0-\epsilon)+\sigma_e\Delta t/2}{\epsilon +\sigma_e\Delta t/2}E_i^n$

$H_S^{n+1/2}=\frac{\mu - \sigma_m\Delta t /2}{\mu + \sigma_m \Delta t/2}H_s^{n-1/2}+\frac{\Delta t}{\mu +\sigma_m \Delta t/2} \nabla\times E_s^n+\frac{(\mu_0 -\mu) -\sigma_m\Delta t/2}{\mu + \sigma_m\Delta t/2}H_i^{n+1/2}-\frac{(\mu_0-\mu)+\sigma_m\Delta t/2}{\mu +\sigma_m\Delta t/2}H_i^{n-1/2}$

Can someone figure it out how they arrived at this solution? I get a $E_s$ term always while trying to solve for either $E_s$ or $H_s$.

Comment: You will find it here in my Google Drive - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wBMQEE5fOhIt70GBPCkfHkO3FOUWI56x/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Since you didn't get an answer, I thought I'd let you know that we have a tag just for TDTD here: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/. You're welcome to ask the question again over there if you're still looking for an answer.